# How to know what country codes navigator.userLanguage; returns for all countries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to detect the language and country of a visiting user of  site. According to this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_userlanguage.asp, it returns the operating system's natural language settings. So it actually returns the OS settings of the user.

My question, how do know I know all the codes that, that function returns for all countries and languages? Is there a list somewhere? For example in Spain it returns es-ES.

Thanks!

```
var userLang = (navigator.language) ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;
```

Comment: Side note: ***NEVER USE W3SCHOOLS***  http://w3fools.com/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533052.aspx - this list is identified by Microsoft as possible `.userLanguage` values. Not sure if this is the same list of the `.language` values.

Comment: @Ian the comments on that page suggest it's an incomplete reference at best.

Comment: @Mathletics Absolutely, I should've said that. But it's the only possible reference I could personally find :) That's why this is a comment, not an answer, but good to point out

Comment: @Ian indeed; edification for all!

Comment: @Dom, I think "NEVER" is a bit strange. Use it as one source from a lot. I know and share w3fools.com's point about "However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on."

Comment: @andras.tim fortunately, that site has improved from what it used to be. A couple years back though, they were complete garbage.